# Newton Rings - Wavelength of light hitting glass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, interference

I'm breaking my head for a long while on an exercise problem and I can't figure it out.

I'm given the distance between the $4^{\text {th}}$ and $25^{\text {th}}$ dark ring, $9$mm. I am given a lens curvature of 15cm.

I need to calculate the wavelength of light. I can't get ring radius without it and I can't figure out what to do with the $9$mm distance between rings. I'm probably supposed to get some kind of radius from it but I'm stumped.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the radius of a ring depend on its number?

Comment: @Pieter I am as confused as you are, friend. Unless that was a question with a point, in which case, it gets bigger the larger it's number is.

Comment: I think that @Pieter ‘s comment is a hint to help you.

Comment: @Farcher Probably, but I can't figure it out. Only thing I'm taking away from that is that the radius increases with it's number which is obvious.

Comment: How does the width of the air gap increase with distance to the point of contact?

Comment: @Pieter I'd assume it increases. This is an entry level high school class and the only two formulas we were given are for the radii of the bright and dark rings where you have the product of the wavelength, lens curvature and ring number under a square root.

Comment: This is a traditional but deplorable way of teaching physics: just feed them formula. But you knew then what I asked, that the ring radius increases as the square root of its number.

Comment: @Pieter Yes, it's directly proportional to it's number. But I can't see how that will help me, I'm still left with one equation with two unknown variables.